# iptables rule for forwarding outbound traffic

Tags: linux, iptables

I am trying to forward the outbound traffic to another server. Current rule is:

> /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s localhost -o 91.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 65000:65010 -j ACCEPT

but when I do a iptables -L, the rule its showed like this:

> ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost.localdomain  anywhere            tcp dpts:65000:65010

So I guess my rule is bad written since the "destination" column shows "anywhere"

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what it looks like you're trying to do, you're probably better off with a route.

`/sbin/route add default gw 91.xxx.xxx.xxx`

You would use iptables for [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

- [Introduction to Linux routing](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-intro.html)
- [Routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 65000:65010 -j DNAT --to ip.of.other.host
```

i assume your FORWARD policy is allow or otherwise such traffic is permitted.